# if/else loop not working properly in Java

Tags: flash, loops, if-statement, actionscript, boolean

I'm trying to write a mobile app using the accelerometer where it plays a sound each time the ball (moved by the accelerometer) reaches the middle horizontal line.

This is my whole code:

```
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.media.SoundChannel;
     import flash.media.Sound;

     var accelX:Number;
     var accelY:Number;
     var tl:sound = new sound();
     var counter:Boolean = false;


     var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
     fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE,
     function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
     {
     accelX = event.accelerationX;
     accelY = event.accelerationY;
     }


     ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
     function moveBall(evt:Event){
     ball.x -= accelX*30;
     ball.y += accelY*30;

     if(ball.x > (480-ball.width/2)){
     ball.x = 480-ball.width/2;
     }
     if(ball.x < (0+ball.width/2)){
     ball.x = 0+ball.width/2;
     }
     if(ball.y > (800-ball.height/2)){
     ball.y = 800-ball.height/2;
     }
     if(ball.y < (0+ball.height/2)){
    ball.y = 0+ball.height/2;
} 
if(ball.y > 398 && ball.y < 402 && counter == false)
{
     tl.play(0, 0);
     counter = true;
     } 
     else
     {  
     counter = false;
     tl.stop;
     }

     }
```

It's the if-else loop at the end that isn't working as intended. It keeps looping the sound when the ball is within the 398 and 402 coordinates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a `Java` code.  `var accelX:Number;`?

Comment: if/else constructs are not loops.

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: try with if{} else if {}

Comment: Its look flash actionscript.

Comment: It's done in Flash which uses ActionScript which is based on JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that the last } isn't on its place, seems like it should be there.

```
if(ball.y > 398 && ball.y < 402 && counter == false)
{
     tl.play(0, 0);
     counter = true;
     } 
     else
     {  
     counter = false;
     tl.stop;
     }

     }
```

Comment: that one is needed to close the brace on line 16
        function moveBall(evt:Event){

my mistake for bad formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

Since stop is a function you need to call it with parenthesis like stop().

Try 
Declare this on top,

```
var soundControl:SoundChannel;
```

then,

```
if(ball.y > 398 && ball.y < 402 && counter == false)
{
  soundControl = tl.play(0, 0);
  counter = true;
} 
else
{  
  counter = false;
  soundControl.stop();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: when I do that, I get the error:
TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.